# How to stop generating wixpdb file in wix setup project?

Tags: wix, wix3

Is there any configuration available to stop generation of wixpdb file.
Since we do not require that file during deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add as per below in your .wixproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
     <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
     <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
     <-- Just Add below line to avoid generation of wixpdb file -->
     <SuppressPdbOutput>true</SuppressPdbOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

Right click Wix Project and go to Properties,
Build → Output → (Check) Suppress output of the wixpdb files

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See the [SuppressPdbOutput](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/light.html) setting in the light build task:

```
Optional boolean parameter.

Specifies that the linker should suppress outputting .wixpdb files. This is 
equivalent to the -spdb switch in light.exe.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

It works for me.

I have added below line in my .wixproj file 'PropertyGroup' xml tag.

`<SuppressPdbOutput>true</SuppressPdbOutput>`

[wix command here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/light.html)